# Set foreground colour based on API call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to render a list of results from an API I've built and as a quick visual reference for people to see if the status is red, amber or green.

I can send the information back as a string or int I'm not really precious about how but I can't get the foreground colour to change on the sf symbol I'm using which is circle.fill

I'm not sure what the best way to feed the data into SwiftUI is as I can't just declare a string for my colour name.

At the moment it's from a variable name that is part of my struct but I need a way for this to ideally be a string or an int. Is there a way in swift that I can pass a colour to a modifier?

```
struct Insight: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let statusColor: Color
    let header: String
    
}


let red: Color = Color(.red)
let yellow: Color = Color(.yellow)
let green: Color = Color(.green)


struct InsightList {
    
    static let topTenInsights = [
        Insight(title: "Some text",
                 statusColor: red,
                 header: "Header"),
        
        Finsight(title: "Some text",
                 statusColor: red,
                 header: "Income") 
]
}
```

```
var insights: [insight] = insightList.topTenInsights

struct Landing: View {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let red: Color = Color(.red)
    let yellow: Color = Color(.yellow)
    let green: Color = Color(.green)
    var body: some View {
        List(insights, id: \.id) { userinsight in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill").foregroundStyle(insight.statusColor)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding()
                    .shadow(radius: 0.9)

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text("Category: \(insight.header)")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    Text(insight.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.9)
                }.padding(13)
                    .shadow(radius: 0.3)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something simple like this:

```
func getStatusColor(_ status: Int) -> Color {
    switch status {
     case 0: return Color.red
     case 1: return Color.yellow
     case 2: return Color.green
     default: return Color.blue
    }
}

Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
.foregroundStyle(getStatusColor(statusValue))
.....
```